# Xcode 7.1.1 Change to SVN from Git, remove Git

Tags: xcode, git, svn

I want to get rid of the link to the git repository

As you can see below clicking on source control still shows the old git remote.

[image]

[image: Shows Git Remote]

I was using both SVN and Git, Xcode was configured with GIT.

What I did was

- delete .git/ in Terminal.
- Delete Git Repositories from XCode preferences
- Add SVN Repository to Xcode Preferences.
- Check out a new working copy Using Source Control - Checkout

I have tried adding a new git and setting the remote or deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is manually edit the files

- .xccheckout
- .xcscmblueprint

Which were located in .xcworkspace I found these by grepping

```
grep -wr git  *
```

I deleted every key value which had git in it.

I am not sure whether I left some superfluous data in it, but so far it seems to be holding up.

As you can see the git part is gone and only my svn remains

[image]

[image]